# Not getting all comments Near Geo Position in MongoDB(Laravel)

Tags: laravel, mongodb-query, geolocation, aggregation-framework

I'm working on app and want to get all comments for a specific post, I created each comment for each country with its lat long(as one post may has many comments), but When I execute query I'm not getting all result, but it shows me only 17 results while there are 200+ comments

> My query is as follows

> db.posts.aggregate([
> { "$geoNear": {
>
> ```
>     "near": [70.0000,30.0000 ],
>     "spherical": true,
>     "distanceField": "distance",
>     "distanceMuliplier": 6371,
>     
> }},
> {
>     "$match":{"post_id":"5efb10c325a36375c97dbda4"}
>  } ])
> ```

and I picked lat long from this link

> https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/1341699

Please help me, Thank you

Comment: you should show more code to understand your problem

Comment: code about query? or db structure?